# chemfig: \definesubmol with a variable

Tags: chemfig

Using the `chemfig` package, I'd like to define a structural element with a variable part. I haven't seen variables being used with `\definesubmol`. And `\newcommand` seems to work only with very simple substitutions:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\definesubmol\A{(-[,-0.3,,,draw=none]1)}
\definesubmol\B{(-[,-0.3,,,draw=none]2)}
\definesubmol\C{(-[,-0.3,,,draw=none]3)}
\definesubmol\D{(-[,-0.3,,,draw=none]4)}

\newcommand\BLUE[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand\X[1]{(-[,-0.3,,,draw=none]{#1})}

\chemfig{*6((!\A)-(!\B)-(!\C)-\BLUE{N}(!\D)---)}
\chemfig{*6((!\A)-(!\B)-(!\C)-\BLUE{N}(!\D)-\X{5}--)}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with `xelatex`:

[image: result]

In the above example, how could I define a better command \X ?

Answer (score 4):

Right now, `\definesubmol` defines macro-submol without argument. The future version 1.4, available [here](https://framagit.org/unbonpetit/chemfig/tree/1.4) and officialy released soon,  allows arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
Version of chemfig: \CFver

With submol-macro:
\definesubmol\X1{-[,-0.3,,,draw=none]#1}
\newcommand*\BLUE[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\chemfig{*6((!\X A)-(!\X B)-(!\X C)-\BLUE{N}(!\X D)---)}% or \chemfig{*6((!\X{A})-(!\X{B})-(!\X{C})-\BLUE{N}(!\X{D})---)}

With submol-name:
\definesubmol X1{-[,-0.3,,,draw=none]#1}
\chemfig{*6((!XA)-(!XB)-(!XC)-\BLUE{N}(!XD)---)}% or \chemfig{*6((!X{A})-(!X{B})-(!X{C})-\BLUE{N}(!X{D})---)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As `\definesubmol` did not allow for additional arguments in earlier version of `chemfig`, you would need to solve it differently. For example like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
 \definesubmol\A{(-[,-0.3,,,draw=none]1)}
 \definesubmol\B{(-[,-0.3,,,draw=none]2)}
 \definesubmol\C{(-[,-0.3,,,draw=none]3)}
 \definesubmol\D{(-[,-0.3,,,draw=none]4)}

 \definesubmol\X{-[,-0.3,,,draw=none]}

 \newcommand\BLUE[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

 \chemfig{*6((!\A)-(!\B)-(!\C)-\BLUE{N}(!\D)---)}
 \chemfig{*6((!\A)-(!\B)-(!\C)-\BLUE{N}(!\D)-(!\X5)--)}

\end{document}
```

But I guess, this approach is not easily applied in every case ...

[image]

This approach still works, but more recent versions of the package allow to use `\definesubmol` with an argument which makes things easier: see the other answer.