# Misaligned numbers in aromatic ring

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I try to number atoms in an aromate using a code of the [chemfig manual](https://ftp.kddilabs.jp/CTAN/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) on page 30.

As seen in the picture the blue number 5 does not align with the other numbers.

Any ideas why `H` in `NH` misaligns my numbering?

PS:
Similar: This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457316/224762) aligns the numbers (in this case letters), but the letters are the same size of the N atom. Using `\scriptstyle` causes the same problem.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

    %%% numbers in ring
    \definesubmol\X1{-[,-0.35,,,draw=none]#1}
    \newcommand\BLUE[1]{\scriptstyle\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

    \definesubmol{D}{*6(((!\X \BLUE{2}))-N(!\X \BLUE{1})(-R|ibose)-(!\X \BLUE{6})(=O)-NH(!\X \BLUE{5})-(!\X \BLUE{4})(=O)-(!\X \BLUE{3})=)}
        
    \chemfig{!D}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must tie the `\X` bond to N instead of H like it is the case in your first code.
You can set the departure atom to 1 in the submol definition:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\definesubmol\X1{-[,-0.35,1,,draw=none]\scriptstyle\color{blue}#1}
\chemfig{*6(((!\X{2}))-N(!\X{1})(-R|ibose)-(!\X{6})(=O)-NH(!\X{5})-(!\X{4})(=O)-(!\X{3})=)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mmh... I also tried this before but it did not work. I must have had a typo. +1

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution to go around it by simply drawing an invisible bond between `N` and `H`.

Nevertheless, suggestions are still appreciate.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}


\begin{document}

    %%% numbers in ring
    \definesubmol\X1{-[,-0.35,,,draw=none]#1}
    \newcommand\BLUE[1]{\scriptstyle\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

    \definesubmol{D}{*6(((!\X \BLUE{2}))-N(!\X \BLUE{1})(-R|ibose)-(!\X \BLUE{6})(=O)-N(-[0,0.26,,,draw=none]H)(!\X \BLUE{5})-(!\X \BLUE{4})(=O)-(!\X \BLUE{3})-[,,1])}
        
    \chemfig{!D}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another approach with the center of the ring

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(-N(-[6]R|ibose)-(=[:-30]O)-NH-(=[2]O)-=)}
\chemmove{\foreach \x in {1,...,6}
    \path (cyclecenter1) ++(330-60*\x:2em) node[blue,font={\scriptsize}] {\x};}
\end{document}
```

[image]